# Spring boot YAML configuration issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I'm using a yaml configuration to configure my spring boot application. the .yaml has only port configuration for the server.  However, when I run the app the YAML configuration file seems to not pick the port number from .yaml file.  I have provided my yaml and console output below.  Not sure why the server doesn't startup at 8282 and still starts with default.

**application.yaml configuration**

```
server:
      port:8282
```

**console output**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.6.RELEASE)

10:33:51 INFO                                           com.vti.Application logStarting               Starting Application on TUSGA00FLKHT01Q with PID 5408 (C:\svn-repository\ivr-callcenter-common-services\target\classes started by v579424 in C:\svn-repository\ivr-callcenter-common-services)
10:33:51 DEBUG                                          com.vti.Application logStarting               Running with Spring Boot v1.2.6.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.7.RELEASE
10:33:51 INFO  ntext.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh            Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3b2c72c2: startup date [Wed Sep 30 10:33:51 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
10:33:52 INFO  rg.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions       Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/beans.xml]
10:33:53 INFO  ngframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition    Overriding bean definition for bean 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=mvcContentNegotiationManager; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]]
10:33:53 INFO  ngframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition    Overriding bean definition for bean 'mvcResourceUrlProvider': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlProvider]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=mvcResourceUrlProvider; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]]
10:33:53 INFO  ngframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition    Overriding bean definition for bean 'mvcPathMatcher': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=mvcPathMatcher; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]]
10:33:53 INFO  ngframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition    Overriding bean definition for bean 'mvcUrlPathHelper': replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=mvcUrlPathHelper; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]]
10:33:53 INFO  rk.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader iddenByExistingDefinition Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=mvcUriComponentsContributor,declaringClass=org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport]: a definition for bean 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
10:33:53 INFO  ngframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition    Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
10:33:54 INFO  framework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties            Loading properties file from class path resource [framework_dev.properties]
10:33:54 INFO  framework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties            Loading properties file from class path resource [data/testdata/testdata_dev.properties]
10:33:54 INFO  framework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties            Loading properties file from class path resource [db/db_dev.properties]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
10:33:54 INFO  t.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker rocessAfterInitialization Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e9fd57a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:33:54 INFO  t.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker rocessAfterInitialization Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:33:54 INFO  t.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker rocessAfterInitialization Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:33:54 INFO  t.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker rocessAfterInitialization Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:33:54 INFO  t.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker rocessAfterInitialization Bean 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a5fd9fd8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:33:54 INFO  t.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker rocessAfterInitialization Bean 'cacheOperationSource' of type [class org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:33:54 INFO  t.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker rocessAfterInitialization Bean 'cacheInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:33:54 INFO  t.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker rocessAfterInitialization Bean 'org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.cache.interceptor.BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:33:55 INFO  .boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer initialize                Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
10:33:55 INFO                 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader ddedWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4473 ms
10:33:57 INFO  pringframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean onStartup                 Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
10:33:57 INFO  springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean configure                 Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
10:33:57 INFO  springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean configure                 Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
10:33:57 INFO                  org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller ateJaxbContextFromClasses Creating JAXBContext with classes to be bound [class com.vzt.ws.stubs.cca.ivrinfows.CallData,class com.vzt.ws.stubs.cca.ivrinfows.GetCallData,class com.vzt.ws.stubs.cca.ivrinfows.IvrTransfer,class com.vzt.ws.stubs.cca.ivrinfows.IvrTransferred,class com.vzt.ws.stubs.weather.Alert,class com.vzt.ws.stubs.weather.DataSet,class com.vzt.ws.stubs.weather.GetAll,class com.vzt.ws.stubs.weather.GetAllResponse,class com.vzt.ws.stubs.weather.Weather,class com.hughestelematics.htimessageheader.MessageHeaderT,class com.hughestelematics.xmlns.webservicesr.WebserviceSRRequest,class com.hughestelematics.xmlns.webservicesr.WebserviceSRReturn,class com.siebel.customui.UpdateSRTypeInput,class com.siebel.customui.UpdateSRTypeOutput,class com.hti.xmlns.webservicepstn.ObjectFactory,class com.hti.xmlns.webservicepstn.PSTNRequestT,class com.hti.xmlns.webservicepstn.PSTNReturnT,class com.hti.xmlns.webservicepstn.PSTNOutput,class com.vti.ws.stubs.provisioning.ApplicationBasicType,class com.vti.ws.stubs.provisioning.ApplicationDetailListRequest,class com.vti.ws.stubs.provisioning.ApplicationDetailListResponse,class com.vti.ws.stubs.provisioning.ApplicationType]
10:33:58 INFO   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName        Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
10:33:58 INFO  .springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler           Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/ctiAgentTransfer/{profileId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.vti.callcenter.model.TransferProfile com.vti.callcenter.web.CTIAgentTransferController.getTransferProfileByProfileId(java.lang.Integer)
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/ctiAgentTransfer/]}" onto public java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer, com.vti.callcenter.model.TransferProfile> com.vti.callcenter.web.CTIAgentTransferController.getTransferProfiles()
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/customAgentRoute/]}" onto public java.util.List<com.vti.callcenter.model.CustomRoute> com.vti.callcenter.web.CustomAgentRouteController.customAgentRoutes()
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/customAgentRoute/{mdn}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.vti.callcenter.model.CustomRoute com.vti.callcenter.web.CustomAgentRouteController.getCustomRougeByMdn(java.lang.String)
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/ivrService/getAllRoutes],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public com.vti.callcenter.model.RouteParamsMap com.vti.callcenter.web.IVRRestController.getAllRouteParms()
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/ivrService/validateDnis],methods=[GET],produces=[text/plain]}" onto public java.lang.String com.vti.callcenter.web.IVRRestController.validateDnis(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/middleware/getDeviceDetails/{mdn}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.vti.callcenter.model.GetDeviceDetailsResponse com.vti.callcenter.web.MiddlewareRestController.getDeviceDetails(java.lang.String)
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3b2c72c2: startup date [Wed Sep 30 10:33:51 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
10:33:58 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3b2c72c2: startup date [Wed Sep 30 10:33:51 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3b2c72c2: startup date [Wed Sep 30 10:33:51 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/ctiAgentTransfer/{profileId}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.vti.callcenter.model.TransferProfile com.vti.callcenter.web.CTIAgentTransferController.getTransferProfileByProfileId(java.lang.Integer)
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/ctiAgentTransfer/]}" onto public java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Integer, com.vti.callcenter.model.TransferProfile> com.vti.callcenter.web.CTIAgentTransferController.getTransferProfiles()
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/customAgentRoute/]}" onto public java.util.List<com.vti.callcenter.model.CustomRoute> com.vti.callcenter.web.CustomAgentRouteController.customAgentRoutes()
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/customAgentRoute/{mdn}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.vti.callcenter.model.CustomRoute com.vti.callcenter.web.CustomAgentRouteController.getCustomRougeByMdn(java.lang.String)
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/ivrService/getAllRoutes],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public com.vti.callcenter.model.RouteParamsMap com.vti.callcenter.web.IVRRestController.getAllRouteParms()
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/ivrService/validateDnis],methods=[GET],produces=[text/plain]}" onto public java.lang.String com.vti.callcenter.web.IVRRestController.validateDnis(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/service/middleware/getDeviceDetails/{mdn}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.vti.callcenter.model.GetDeviceDetailsResponse com.vti.callcenter.web.MiddlewareRestController.getDeviceDetails(java.lang.String)
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
10:33:59 INFO  b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod     Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
10:33:59 INFO  .springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler           Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
10:33:59 INFO  .springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler           Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
10:33:59 INFO  .springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler           Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
10:33:59 INFO  pringframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter terSingletonsInstantiated Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
10:33:59 INFO  .boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer start                     Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
10:33:59 INFO                                           com.vti.Application logStarted                Started Application in 8.7 seconds (JVM running for 9.813)
```

Comment: I think the file should be placed in `src/main/resources/` not `src/main/resources/configuration`. Also the extension should be `yml` not `yaml` (Spring documentation: If YAML is used then files with the ‘.yml’ extension are also added to the list by default.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I tried it in src/main/resources/ directory but still it doesn't get loaded.

Comment: And what about the extension? See me edited comment

Comment: yes, I did that to. but still couldn't load this file.  FYI, I'm setting the spring.profiles.active as a -D VM argument when I'm running it in eclipse.

Comment: I noticed you are loading your own property files in your xml configuration is it possible that we are overriding something in there? Can we view the relevant areas of the xml and the annotations on the main application class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After copy pasting your code from this page straight into my project it also didn't work. It had 2 tabs in front of port which it needs to be spaces and between port, :, and 8282 there was no space(It requires one space apparently) both of these issues caused it to load as port 8080 for me.(Failed silently)

Instead I came up with this

```
server:
    port: 8282
```

And this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @Zergleb.  it worked for me.  It seems to be a bug in the spring yml. it should remote the tab or space instead of filing silently.

Comment: You're welcome. This isn't a problem with snakeyaml(YAML library used by Spring) or Spring itself. Check out this online yaml parser for example http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and put both inputs in. Not adding a space is the same a defining a string in yaml that happens to have a : in it.(Meaning this is how any yaml parser would treat it.)